# HTML Image Absolute Path When Image Outside Web Server Root

Tags: php, html

I am trying to load images in HTML.
I am using the application only for myself locally.
I am using Windows10.
Moving the image somewhere else under the web server is not an option.
I am using Apache Web Server.
The path is this:

```
D:/cover.jpg
```

and the HTML is:

```
<img src="D:/cover.jpg" alt="Cover">
```

But, however I try, it won't display it.
I tried with:

```
<img src="file:///D:/cover.jpg" alt="Cover">
```

but also does not display. Is it so, that only images relative to web server root can be displayed?

Comment: What web server are you using? IIS, Apache?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your slash after your drive. It needs to be:

```
<img src="file:///D:\cover.jpg" alt="Cover">
```